Running useFormState dispatch with data
I want to validate data from a form before passing it to a server. For this, I want to direct the form action property to a function, which would validate the data on the client side and run the formAction if everything is correct. But I don't understand how to pass data from form action to function and from function to formAction function. I use next.js, typescript. I want to use form state, to have formState variable, but if I call formAction, it doesn't expect any arguments, even though I want to give it my data from form. How to pass data to the validateData function, and then to formAction?
I use next.js 14.2.5, react and react-dom 18.2
Here is an MVP of my problem.
"use client";
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import farServerFunction from "./func.ts";

export default function Page() {
  const [formState, formAction] = useFormState(farServerFunction, null);
  const validateData = (data: FormData) => {
    const name = data.get("name") as string;
    if (name.length < 5) {
      alert("Name must be at least 5 characters long.");
      return;
    }
    formAction(data); // Expected 0 arguments, but got 1
  }
  return <form action={validateData}>
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>;
}


I tried googling, chatGPT and searching documentation but found it confusing and not enough to understand.

It turns out that useFormState works by adapting to the function you pass inside. So if you pass a test function with nothing inside of it yet, it would have no arguments expected. So the solution is to define the function with necessary arguments (e.g. "_: any, formData: FormData"), and when you pass an argument when you call formAction, it won't raise an error.
